# Javascript to select multiple select list

Tags: javascript

I have following select list from which user can select multiple option

```
<select size="6" onblur="validatevalumethod()" multiple="" id="valumethod[]" name="valumethod[]"> 
        <option value="0">Select Asset</option>

        <option value="OC">ORIGINAL COST</option>
        <option value="OCUIP">ORIGINAL COST USING INDEXED PRICES</option>
        <option value="RC">REPLACEMENT COST</option>
        <option value="OCCR">ORIGINAL COST CONSIDERING REVALUATION</option>
        <option value="OCUIPCR">ORIGINAL COST USING INDEXED PRICES & CONSIDERING REVALUATION</option>
        <option value="RCCR">REPLACEMENT COST CONSIDERING REVALUATION</option>
        </select>
```

I need to fetch the value selected by user in javascript but dont know how to do this please help me.

Comment: Do you know what are the arrows, numbers, checkmarks beside each answer/question for? ... and why you have `Accept_rate = 0;` ? Can you show us your first try to solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you could do 
`$("#list option:selected").text();` to get the text of the selected option
`$("#list option:selected").val();` to get the value behind the selected option

EDIT:

where #list is the id of your select tag

Answer (score 1):

I think that the following solution is better to fetch VALUES :

```
$("#list option:selected").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very simple code that tells you how many you selected on every change:

For the Html Code:

```
<html>
<body>

<select multiple="true">
  <option>Volvo</option>
  <option>Saab</option>
  <option>Mercedes</option>
  <option>Audi</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

​Use this jQuery Code:

```
$("select").change(function() {
    alert($("option:selected").length);
});
```

Here's a live example:
http://jsfiddle.net/hesher/3M36e/

Answer (score 1):

You can use pure javascript as in :
    document.getElementById('valumethod[]').value